# Большой массив строчных данных

Tags: python, файлы, аналитика

У меня имеются файл по 300 ГБ и более мне нужно сравнить их между собой и создать 3 файл в который будут добавлены все строки из остальных и добавлен 1 раз дубликат.
Какими путями можно решить эту проблему используя Python.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно понять. Как без использования БД (чтобы быстрей происходил процесс) вывести 3 файл из других с уникальными строка.  И включенным 1 раз дублем если он имеется..

Comment: `cat f1 f2 | sort -u > f3`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Вы не дали развернуться программистскому сообществу во всю мощь :-)

Comment: @rotabor, задача не лишена смысла. Возможно, с помощью хеш-функции её можно решить быстрее чем это сделает `sort -u`. Требуется проверка.

Comment: Есть одна маленькая проблема общий обьем файлов 33 миллиарда строк